# How to display continuous data coming from a BLE peripheral in a UITextbox in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im currently interacting with a ble peripheral, I can read and write to the ble peripheral and display the incoming data in a textbox.

Now upon button click I'm using the read and write bytes in a function block that I'm calling in the button click action.

```
@IBAction func data(_ sender: Any) {

        checkdata()
    }
```

Now my Question,

I have a continuous flow of byte arrays from my receiving end that I need to display into my textbox constantly? Can someone guide me on how its done?

```
//Now my function 
fun checkdata(){

//WRITE CODE 

let bytes : [UInt8] = [ 0x1A, 0x2B, 0x3C, 0x4D ]
            let Transmitdata = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
            peripheral.writeValue(Transmitdata as Data, for: txCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
            print("Data Sent",Transmitdata)


//READ CODE

  let ReceiveData = rxCharacteristic?.value
            if let ReceiveData = ReceiveData {
                let ReceivedNoOfBytes = ReceiveData.count
                myByteArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: ReceivedNoOfBytes)
                (ReceiveData as NSData).getBytes(&myByteArray, length: ReceivedNoOfBytes)
                print("Data Received ",myByteArray)
                   }


//DISPLAY RECEIVED DATA

var b0 = myByteArray[0]
var b1 = myByteArray[1]
var b2 = myByteArray[2]
var b3 = myByteArray[3]



datatextbox1.text = "\(b0)"
datatextbox2.text = "\(b1)"
datatextbox3.text = "\(b2)"
datatextbox4.text = "\(b3)"

}
```

So the receiving data with be continuous until another button touchinside is performed. (INEFFICIENT/NOT WORKING)

```
//DATA IS DISPLAYED UNTIL NEXT BUTTON IS PRESSED

while(self.stopbutton.touchInside = true){
//WRITE DATA
//READ DATA
//DISPLAY DATA
}
```

EDIT 1: TRYING FUNC DIDUPDATE VALUE

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    guard let mydata = rxCharacteristic.value else { return }

 //READ CODE

      let ReceiveData = rxCharacteristic?.value
                if let ReceiveData = ReceiveData {
                    let ReceivedNoOfBytes = ReceiveData.count
                    myByteArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: ReceivedNoOfBytes)
                    (ReceiveData as NSData).getBytes(&myByteArray, length: ReceivedNoOfBytes)
                    print("Data Received ",myByteArray)
                       }


    //DISPLAY RECEIVED DATA

    var b0 = myByteArray[0]
    var b1 = myByteArray[1]
    var b2 = myByteArray[2]
    var b3 = myByteArray[3]



    datatextbox1.text = "\(b0)"
    datatextbox2.text = "\(b1)"
    datatextbox3.text = "\(b2)"
    datatextbox4.text = "\(b3)"

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need to send a request to your device I order to get it to send data or does it send data using a BLE `Notify?

Comment: @Paulw11 hi Paul thanks for your response, the first write data is sent only once for request and then the custom ble will be sending continuous data to rxcharacterstics

Comment: Then you should enable notifications https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518949-setnotifyvalue and then you will get asynchronous calls to `didUpdateValue`

Comment: @Paulw11 I have tried it but not sure where I should put it? Can I put it as a seperate function and read the characteristic from the peripheral?

Comment: Have you read the Core Bluetooth programming guide and the documentation for CBPeripheral? Once you turn on notification for your characteristic you will get calls to the didUpdateValue delegate method. Edit your question to show what you have tried

Comment: @Paulw11 please find my edit, thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161839/discussion-between-paulw11-and-nar0909).